# SQL not Updating Data

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to update data in table in JavaFX. For some reason it wouldn't work. Anyone has an idea what could be wrong in the following code?

```
public void replaceData(ActionEvent event) {

    try {

        Connection conn = SqliteConnection.Connector();
        this.data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(
                "UPDATE "+SupermarketDB+" SET ProductName='" + ProductName1.getText() + "', Barcode=" + Barcode1.getText() + ", Category=" + Category1.getText() + ", SubCategory=" + SubCategory1.getText() + ", TotalStock='" + TotalStock1.getText() + "' Where ID=" + ID2.getText() + "");


        this.dataid.setText(ProductName1.getText());
        this.dataBarcode.setText(Barcode1.getText());
        this.dataCategory.setText(Category1.getText());
        this.dataSubCategory.setText(SubCategory1.getText());
        this.dataTotalStock.setText(TotalStock1.getText());
        this.dataSinglePrice.setText(SinglePrice1.getText());

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: probably something wrong in the code you are not showing :) Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: It's better to use a `PreparedStatement` for creating a query containing data you need to insert based on the gui input. Furthermore by leaving the `catch` empty, you ignore information that could be valuable for debugging. NEVER do this, unless the exception is an expected result. (At least put `ex.printStackTrace();` in there.) There are other issues though: There is a `,` just before `WHERE` and you use `executeQuery` for a update query.

Answer (score 0):

You did mistake in query statement you put comma before where close. Just delete that comma

```
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(
                "UPDATE "+SupermarketDB+" SET ProductName=" + ProductName1.getText() + ", Barcode=" + Barcode1.getText() + ", Category=" + Category1.getText() + ", SubCategory=" + SubCategory1.getText() + ", TotalStock=" + TotalStock1.getText() + " Where ID=" + ID2.getText() + "");
```

paste this code

Comment: This won't work either, even if the `TextField`s do not contain quotes... This is an update query, not a query returning a `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

At least two issues here:

1. `UPDATE` statements do not return the updated row (would be nice if they did...) So you cannot expect to get a `ResultSet` from an update statement. Had you been using `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()` this would have been easier to spot.
2. Instead of quoting the parameters when forming the SQL string, it is better to use a `PreparedStatement`. I.e., use something like:

   ```
   String sql = "UPDATE " + SupermarketDB + " SET ProductName=?, Barcode=?, Category=?, SubCategory=?, TotalStock=? Where ID=?");
   try(Connection conn = SqliteConnection.Connector();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        int i = 0;       
        stmt.setString(++i, ProductName1.getText());
        ..
        stmt.setString(++i, ID2.getText());

        stmt.executeUpdate();
   }
   ```

   The above also ensures that the connection is properly closed.